# allow certain IP from the block list for Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am blocking china ip block using the code as following,but it just confused me what should i do if i just want few IP for example 1.202.10.20(They are in the block CIDR Ranges)  allowed for access.

"require ip" or "allow from" will lead to block all or internal server error. Thank you very much!

```
<Files *>
  <RequireAll>
    Require all granted
# Chinese (CN) IP addresses follow:
Require not ip 1.68.0.0/14 1.80.0.0/13 1.92.0.0/14 1.192.0.0/13 1.202.0.0/15 1.204.0.0/14 14.144.0.0/12 14.208.0.0/12 23.80.54.0/24 23.104.141.0/24 23.105.14.0/24 23.226.208.0/24 27.8.0.0/13 27.16.0.0/12 27.36.0.0/14 27.40.0.0/13 27.50.128.0/17 27.54.192.0/18 27.106.128.0/18 27.115.0.0/17 27.148.0.0/14 27.152.0.0/13 27.184.0.0/13 36.32.0.0/14 36.248.0.0/14 39.128.0.0/10 42.96.128.0/17 42.120.0.0/15 42.156.0.0/16 43.255.0.0/20 43.255.16.0/22 43.255.48.0/22 43.255.60.0/22 43.255.64.0/20 43.255.96.0/20 43.255.144.0/22 43.255.168.0/22 43.255.176.0/22 43.255.184.0/22 43.255.192.0/22 43.255.200.0/21 43.255.208.0/21 43.255.224.0/21 43.255.232.0/22 43.255.244.0/22 54.222.0.0/15 58.16.0.0/15 58.20.0.0/16 58.21.0.0/16 58.22.0.0/15 58.34.0.0/16 58.37.0.0/16 58.38.0.0/16 58.40.0.0/16 58.42.0.0/16 58.44.0.0/14 58.48.0.0/13 58.56.0.0/15 58.58.0.0/16 58.59.0.0/17 58.60.0.0/14 58.68.128.0/17 58.82.0.0/15 58.100.0.0/15 58.208.0.0/12 58.242.0.0/15 58.246.0.0/15 58.248.0.0/13 59.32.0.0/12 59.51.0.0/16 59.52.0.0/14 59.56.0.0/13 59.72.0.0/16 59.108.0.0/15 59.172.0.0/14 60.0.0.0/13 60.11.0.0/16 60.12.0.0/16 60.24.0.0/13 60.160.0.0/11 60.194.0.0/15 60.208.0.0/12 61.4.64.0/20 61.4.80.0/22 61.4.176.0/20 61.48.0.0/13 61.128.0.0/10 61.135.0.0/16 61.136.0.0/18 61.139.0.0/16 61.145.73.208/28 61.147.0.0/16 61.150.0.0/16 61.152.0.0/16 61.154.0.0/16 61.160.0.0/16 61.162.0.0/15 61.164.0.0/16 61.172.0.0/15 61.175.0.0/16 61.177.0.0/16 61.179.0.0/16 61.183.0.0/16 61.184.0.0/16 61.185.219.232/29 61.187.0.0/16 61.188.0.0/16 61.232.0.0/14 61.236.0.0/15 61.240.0.0/14 101.64.0.0/13 101.72.0.0/14 101.76.0.0/15 101.80.0.0/12 103.253.4.0/22 106.80.0.0/12 106.108.0.0/14 106.112.0.0/13 


  </RequireAll>

</Files>
```

Comment: require all granted is the basic rule and is overriden by require not ip. I doubt you can override the override.

Comment: kindly give advice on how to do it,thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to explicitly specify all blocked addresses with no exceptions, even if that means you'll have hundreds of them in the file.

Comment: thanks,it seems no other better option.